# Is there a way for python to check multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

Is there a way for python to check multiple values for "not equals to"? Like:

```
if len(dict) != 2 or 4 or 8 or 16 or 32:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `set`:

```
if len(dict) not in {2, 4, 8, 16, 32}:
    do_something()
```

Comment: Better still: use a set: `if len(dict) not in {2, 4, 8, 16, 32}:`.

Comment: that right - it's faster